# JFileChooser returns wrong file name?

Tags: java, file, swing, jfilechooser

```
final JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
int returnVal = fc.showOpenDialog(this);

if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
    String fileName = fc.getSelectedFile().getName();
    String path = (new File(fileName)).getAbsolutePath();
}
```

The absolute path I get is the concatenation of the project directory and *fileName*!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29) return the `File` object.

Why are you getting the file name and instantiating a new `File` object again?

Can you try:

```
fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Answer (score 2):

That's what `getAbsolutePath()` does - gets the full path, including drive letter (if you're on Windows), etc. What are you trying to get, just the file name?

After you initialize your `File` object, you can get just the file name from that, OR you can use [`JFileChooser.getSelectedFile()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JFileChooser.html#getSelectedFile%28%29)

If you're getting `/path/to/filefilename` but you're expecting `/path/to/file/filename` then you can add an extra slash to the path as appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Because you created new file `new File(fileName)` using returned filename, that means relative path. Use `fc.getSelectedFile().getPath()` or `fc.getSelectedFile().getAbsolutePath()` instead.